# Адаптация сайта под мобильные устройства

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, mobile

Подскажите как оптимизировать сайт под мобильные устройства
Сделал чтобы с компьютера отображалось 60% контента по центру, под мобильные необходимо сделать 100% контента.
Я сделал это так:

```
.content{
width: 100%;
}
.content_center{
width: 60%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

на мобильном отображается как и на компьютере 60% контента

буду благодарен если объясните простыми словами, ну или хотябы ткните где почитать про это

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
   .content_center{
      width: 100%;
   }
}
```

Используй `@media (max-width: ...px)`

Comment: уже разобрался, сейчас проблема со шрифтами, использовать шрифт в px в @media или лучше в основном css прописать шрифт в em?